# How to get current search query in a search page

Tags: 2013, javascript, search

In a SharePoint 2013 publishing site, I have a custom search page.

This page can be reach from the search box in the master page. It lands on : `http://server/pages/search.aspx?k=myquery`, which is expected.

In this page, I have a search zone, and a result webpart. If I type a new search from this page, I land on: `http://server/pages/search.aspx?k=myquery#k=mynewquery`.

Is there any way to get the current query from a javascript code?

Actually, I have a custom webpart that requires to get this query. My current webpart (inherited from SP2010) relies on the query string from C# code, but this does not work with SP 2013 due to this new pure ajax page update.

Thanks for advise.

PS: my alternative would be to parse the url (looking for the `k` query string first after the #, then in the url query).

Comment: I think latter is the only option

Comment: Are you saying that the Query String for "k" is not returning "mynewquery"?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott: yes, the query string still contains `myquery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using self parsing code, I can find my query using :

```
// In a global utility.js file
(function () {
    window.UrlQuery = window.UrlQuery || (function () {
        var result = {
            hash: {},
            query: {}
        };

        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var vars = query.split("&");
        for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split("=");
            result.query[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        }

        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        var hashVars = hash.split("&");
        for (var i = 0; i < hashVars.length; i++) {
            var pair = hashVars[i].split("=");
            if (pair.length > 1) {
                result.hash[pair[0]] = pair[1];
            }
        }

        return result;
    })();
})();
```

And when I need to get the query :

```
        var kQuery = window.UrlQuery.hash.k || window.UrlQuery.query.k || null;
        var rQuery = window.UrlQuery.hash.r || window.UrlQuery.query.r || null;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the Search Query Val by Using Search OOB Object.

`Srch.ScriptApplicationManager.get_current().queryGroups['Default'].dataProvider.get_currentQueryState().k`

Answer (score 2):

```
function getQuery(group) {
return Srch.ScriptApplicationManager.get_current().queryGroups[group].dataProvider.$2_3;
}

function getDefaultQuery() {
 return getQuery("Default");
}
```