# In a search display template, is there a search property available for the actual text (k=...) in Srch.U or any of the search objects?

Tags: javascript, search, display-template, query

I'm trying to add the searched text value to the query string in the url (`<a href='...?searchText=[something]'>Title</a>`)

In the search display templates, I see ctx and Srch objects exist that have a lot of properties about the current item and general search properties. However, I'm having an issue trying to get the actual searched value (in pairs or all in one string). I can extract it from the url hash since it's not in the querystring anymore, but I was wondering if there was a more standardized way to do this.

edit: for now, I have two methods to extract a querystring value and a hash value, and setting searchText (which is conditionally appended to the url) in the following way:

```
var searchText = "&searchText=" + GetHashVal("k") || GetQueryVal("k");
```

Comment: I'm not clear can you explain, why search term is not in the querystring?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 puts it in the hash if the user searches on the page. I believe their reasoning is because it lets the UI change without the page refreshing. The same happens on list views now.

Comment: Maybe here some ideas: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114480/how-to-get-current-search-query-in-a-search-page

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve it from the DataProvider object. Which is accessible from within your display template.

```
ctx.DataProvider.get_currentQueryState()
```

This returns an object which gives you the whole search query context, like: keyword, sorting, refinement, ...

In your case you want to extract the keyword, which you can retrieve from the property like this:

```
var keyword = ctx.DataProvider.get_currentQueryState().k;
```

Comment: I had to load sp.js with $includeScript which added the SP.ClientContext object, but DataProvider is still undefined.

Comment: ctx.DataProvider should be available from inside your display template. As this is also used for rendering the results. No need to load other files.